# vsftpd could not open /etc/security

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

Cannot list the directory using winscp from windows 10.  Same vsftpd.conf works on Ubuntu 16 with winscp.

vsftpd[2371]: pam_unix(vsftpd:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory

/etc/security is a directory in Ubuntu 20.04

```
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root    4096 Feb  9 12:51 security
```

Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

```
ken@Sun:/etc$ cat vsftpd.conf
listen=YES
listen_ipv6=NO
connect_from_port_20=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=40000
pasv_max_port=45000
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.userlist
userlist_deny=NO
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with winscp/file explorer not listing the directory was solved by opening up the ftp ports

sudo ufw allow 40000:45000/tcp